# string not recognized as valid datetime with same format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this string: 02/01/2019 13:00:00
I want get only the `02/01/2019`, so I did:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(match.datetime.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date.ToString();
```

nb: `match.datetime` contains the value `02/01/2019 13:00:00`

but I get this error:

> string not recognized as valid datetime

Comment: Is `match.datetime` a `System.DateTime` itself? if so you can get the short format by using `Console.WriteLine(match.datetime.Date);`

Comment: Why are you formatting a datetime into a string just to parse it back into a DateTime?

Comment: @Amy just learning exercise..

Comment: @Baklap4 this will give also the 00 part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

24 hour time is represented by `HH` for parsing, not `hh`.

Try something like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("02/01/2019 13:00:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your format ("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss") you're specifying a 12-hour representation with "hh", but you're input is outside of that range: "13:00:00".